# Editor might not refreshing after file touch

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

We develop a plug-in for Eclipse, and my problem is that when I try to refresh my opened editors with ***touch()*** it just sometimes not refreshes some of them, but after I put a space (or anything which modifies the file) in the code (in the non-refreshed one) it refreshes automatically after it.

My code for the file refresh is the following:

```
IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow(); 
if(window != null){
    IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();

        if(page != null){
            IEditorReference[] editRefs = page.getEditorReferences();
            for(IEditorReference e : editRefs){
                try{
                    IFile file = (IFile) e.getEditorInput().getAdapter(IFile.class);
                    if(file != null){
                        file.touch(null);
                    }
                } catch(CoreException exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Has anyone seen this problem before? Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it predictable what type of editor fails to refresh? Possibly the editor is not listening for resource changes.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer.  

So I meant editor in Eclipse. Here is a picture what I meant under word editor:
http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.jst.jsf.doc.user/html/gettingstarted/wpe/images/wpe.png  

And it works 9/10 times, but sometimes it just not refreshing. There is no error in console, it just doesn't do anything at all.

This editor refresh is called from a Property window, and called after button OK is pushed.  

And the problem is usual, when I have more than 1 editor opened, not the one which is focused, but one or more from the others are not refreshing

Comment: Yes. but there are many different editors in Eclipse - Java editor, text editor, plugin.xml editor, ..... Each different editor has the deal with external resources changes itself and there are a few which don't have this code.